# How to get phone notch size in Unity?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, screen

I'm trying to find out the phone notch size in the Unity3d application.
The phone is Android(not iOS).
I thought the solution is to get the notch size is:

Screen.height - Screen.safeArea.height.

But the problem is that they are equal when you have turned off the "Render outside of safe area" flag from player settings.
I need that value to move natively render window(the map) into the correct position, because it starts the calculation form Screen top left corner, not from the safe area's corner.
Is there any solution to get notch size?

Comment: Seems like Notch size is relative to the device: https://phonesized.com/notch/

Comment: @Lotan Yes, you are right. But I need a way to find that value.